# Press Button on Webpage with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to click a button on a webpage using VBA. The button is within a `<button>` tag, as in the code snipped below:

```
<div class="search-options-container">
<button class="aui-item aui-button aui-button-subtle search-button"
 type="button" original-title="Search for Issues">
<span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-search">Search</span></button>
</div>
```

The code I am using so far is:

```
Dim ieApp As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim ieElement As Object
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
...

Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

For Each oHTML_Element In ie.Document.getElementsByName("button")
  Debug.Print ("REACHED")
  If oHTML_Element.className = "aui-item aui-button aui-button-subtle search-button" Then
    oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
Next
```

Which gives me an object required error. I also tried using:

```
ieElement = ieApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
```

Which also gives an object required error.

Edit: Corrected the search string as pointed out by user Jordan. 
The Debug.Print does not execute, so the error probably already arises, when looking for the element with .getElementsByName . The script is already able to open the page and enter text in a search box before clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are searching for elements in an index that doesn't exist. In the html example you have provided there is not an element collection named "button".

Secondly, the class name you are searching for in your current code is:

```
"aui-item aui-button-subtle search-button"
```

However in your html example the class name of the button is:

```
"aui-item aui-button aui-button-subtle search-button"
```

Try replacing your `For` loop with:

```
ieApp.Document.getElementsbyClassName("aui-item aui-button aui-button-subtle search-button")(0).Click
```

Comment: It's these kind of errors, why programming may be hated. It still gives the error though.

Comment: Also, as far as I can see there is no object 'ie' in the code. Shouldn't you be using 'ieApp' and not 'ie'?

Comment: Your suggested replacement still prompts the object required error.

Comment: @Seppelpeters is the code in your question all of your code? Are you not navigating to the page at an earlier stage?

Comment: Yes, the page is situated on an intranet though, so I thought providing the link would be of little use. Before clicking the button, the script already successful enters text into a search box.

Comment: Thanks @Zac, I've edited the answer to include this. @Seppelpeters did you try the line of code with new edit, using `ieApp` not `ie`.

Comment: I inserted some more code to wait for the page to load, and it is working now with @Jordan 's answer. Thank you for your answers and diligence!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the classic example for this kind of question.

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html

And here is all the code.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```